# Difference between i++ and ++i

Tags: c

So, I understand that i++ increments post the condition is fulfilled, while ++i increments before the condition is fulfilled. That takes me to my question:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i=0;
    while(++i<10)
        printf("%d\n",i);
    return 0;
}
```

Now here we need the initialization of i from 0 as when it goes in the while loop, it will get incremented first, and thus it will be like while(1<10), and so it will print numbers from one to ten.

Second code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i=0;
    while(i++<10)
        printf("%d\n",i);
    return 0;
}
```

Now since i++ increments after the value has been used, so why do we initialize i from i=0, as if it gets incremented after the comparision of value of i takes place, then why isn't 0 getting printed as well because the first loop should go like while(0<10), and not like while(1<10)? So, why is zero not getting printed?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: But it's written that i++ increments after the comparison, so, then what's the difference between ++i and i++?

Comment: The better question to ask is "why does one loop print 10, and the other does not?"

Comment: Note that "after the comparison" occurs before the printf.

Comment: With i++ you get numbers from 1 to 10, while with ++i you get numbers from 1 to 9. If I put a breakpoint and go step by step then you can see that after the comparison the number i is incremented, so in the print it will start always with 1.

Comment: `"Now since i++ increments after the value has been used"` -- This statement is not quite correct. The expression `i++` will evaluate to the value that `i` had before incrementing. But this does not specify whether the actual incrementation takes place before or after evaluating the `if` condition. See this question for further information: [Why are these constructs using pre and post-increment undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/949433/12149471)

Comment: @sheldor: Your claim that the debugger will show that the compiler will always increment `i` after the comparison, is not necessarily correct. First of all, the compiler is always free to reorder instructions under the [as-if rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718262/what-exactly-is-the-as-if-rule). For example, it may make a copy of `i`, then increment `i`, and then compare the copy. Also, even without the as-if rule, as I have pointed out in my previous comment, the incrementation operation is unsequenced with respect to the comparison.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the first condition will evaluate to `0 < 10`. You can verify that by changing it to `while (i++ < 1)` and see that the loop still runs (once), so clearly it's using 0 for the condition (`1 < 1` would be false of course).

So why does it print 1? Because it doesn't print whichever value was used for the condition. It prints the current value of `i`. And the current value of `i` is 1 at that point because `i` was incremented right after it was used in the condition.

Answer (score 3):

Zero isn't printed because `i` is incremented *right after the comparison*, like this:

```
while(i<10) {
    i += 1;
    printf("%d\n",i);
}
```

The first sentence of your question is almost the answer:

> `i++` increments post the condition is fulfilled

It's incremented after the condition is *checked*, so `i++ < 10` will increment `i` regardless of whether the condition ends up true or false.

Comment: Also, compare this with `while( i += 1, i < 10 )`

Answer (score 3):

The difference of pre- and post- increment applies only to the value that the expression evaluates to.

After the evaluation of `i++<10` is completed, the incrementation is also completed, and `i` has the value `1` in the first iteration.

`printf("%d\n",i);` is executed after the evaluation of `i++<10`, so `i` has the value `1` here in the first iteration.

Answer (score 1):

The operation of `++` is not done before or after any “condition” it is in. It must be completed sometime in or around the *full expression* it is in. The answers that say `i` is updated “before” or “after” the `++i` or `i++` is evaluated are incorrect.

Prefix `++i` does two **separate** things that may happen in any order:

- It evaluates to the value of `i` after one is added.
- It adds one to the stored value of `i`.

Postfix `i++` does two **separate** things that may happen in any order:

- It evaluates to the value of `i` before one is added.
- It adds one to the stored value of `i`.

That change to the stored value of `i` is called a *side effect*. It is disconnected from the main evaluation of the expression. It can be performed before, during, or after the evaluation of `i`, but the evaluation still returns the pre- or post-increment value, as described above.

A *full expression* is one that is not contained inside another expression. So, in `while (++i < 10)`, `++i < 10` is a full expression. The side effect can occur before any part of that is evaluated, after the value of `i` plus one is calculated, or after the `<` is evaluated. It can also occur in parts (such as updating the bytes of `i` one by one) during the evaluations. However, the side effect must occur after any previous full expression and before any later full expression. That is because the C standard says there is a sequence point between any two full expressions. (And there are some other rules about order of execution.)

Even if the stored value of `i` is updated before `i++` or after `++i`, the expression must still produce the value of `i` before or after the increment, respectively. For example, for `i++`, the compiler can fetch `i`, add one, store `i`, but then use the pre-add value in the expression.

Answer (score 1):

The *result* of `i++` is the value of `i`.  As a *side effect* `i` is incremented.

The result of `++i` is the value of `i + 1`.  As a side effect `i` is incremented.

The statement

```
x = i++;
```

is logically equivalent to

```
tmp = i;
x = tmp;
i = i + 1;
```

with the caveat that the assignments to `x` and `i` can happen in any order, or even simultaneously (interleaved or in parallel).

Similarly, the statement

```
x = ++i;
```

is logically equivalent to

```
tmp = i + 1;
x = tmp;
i = i + 1;
```

with the same caveat as above.  Again, these are *logical* equivalents, not what the compiler actually generates - depending on the compiler and the code involved there may not be a temporary.

Answer (score 1):

In the second code, the increment will take place after the condition but before the printing statement.

Thus, the incremented value of `i` is printed.

This is your answer in simple language.